# Ios Appirater is not working properly in Ios 10

Tags: appirater

rate the app in ios , so i am using Appirater framework . but it's not working properly . Here is my code . after 5 day i have to set . and i am in debug mode .

```
 [Appirater setAppId:@"456546456"];
    [Appirater setDaysUntilPrompt:0];
    [Appirater setUsesUntilPrompt:0];
    [Appirater setSignificantEventsUntilPrompt:-1];
    [Appirater setTimeBeforeReminding:0];
    [Appirater setDebug:YES];
    [Appirater appLaunched:YES];
```

when i click on button that time i have to open this alert here is my code.

```
[Appirater userDidSignificantEvent:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a positive value to `setSignificantEventsUntilPrompt:`. A negative value configures Appirater to ignore significant events, which is why you're call to `userDidSignificantEvnet:` does nothing.

Also, remove `setDebug:`. It's not useful for you here. :-)